# "Icon(s) not replaced" error when building product with Tycho

Tags: maven, icons, eclipse-rcp, tycho, p2

I'm using Tycho 0.16.0 and I'm getting the following error:

```
Error - 7 icon(s) not replaced in C:\Users\weich01\AppData\Local\Temp\p2.brandingIron8219115442087687624\launcher.exe using C:\Development\Workspaces\Workspace RCP SR2\de.mycompany.myproduct.product\target\products\MyProduct\de.mycompany.myproduct.feature\logo_pms_2011.ico
```

With the export wizard in Eclipse, everything works fine, so product definition is correct. The icon file contains bitmaps in all sizes.

Comment: did you check this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999323/error-in-tycho-while-replacing-the-product-ico-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check your product configuration file (*.product). The path to icons should be relative to product project. So for example with project:

```
com.myapplication.product/
    myProduct.product
    icons/
        application.ico
```

your myProduct.product file should look like this:

```xml
 ...
 <launcher name="executable">
   <linux icon="icons/application.xpm"/>
   <macosx icon="icons/application_32.icns"/>
   <solaris/>
   <win useIco="true">
      <ico path="icons/application.ico"/>
      <bmp/>
   </win>
 </launcher>
 ...
```

Check this sample of tycho product configuration:
https://github.com/jsievers/tycho-demo/tree/master/tychodemo.product

Comment: I had this wrong, because I used the Eclipse File Selector, which added the name of the compont to the location like 'project/icons/application.ico'. I had to manually edit the product file as a text file to make it work.
Thanks for the hint!